# My data .sql isn't recognized as a database using sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

i'm trying to import my data (.sql) and convert it to .csv in my python code.
I choose to use sqlite3 to connect the data.sql, but i find this error:

(I leave the code and the error below)

```
import sqlite3

# Open the file
f = open('output.csv', 'w')
# Create a connection and get a cursor
connection = sqlite3.connect('data.sql')
cursor = connection.cursor()
# Execute the query
cursor.execute('select * from data')
# Get data in batches
while True:
    # Read the data
    df = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchmany(1000))
    # We are done if there are no data
    if len(df) == 0:
        break
    # Let's write to the file
    else:
        df.to_csv(f, header=False)

# Clean up
f.close()
cursor.close()
connection.close()



cursor.execute('select * from data')
sqlite3.DatabaseError: file is not a database
```

Comment: Which format has data.sql? SQL commands in text form?

Comment: [`.sql`](https://fileinfo.com/extension/sql) != [`.db`](https://fileinfo.com/extension/db)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to open SQL dump instead of a database file. First convert your SQL dump to actual SQLite database by running:

```
sqlite3 data.db <data.sql
```

And replace `data.db` with `data.sql` in your code.

[See a tutorial](https://linuxhint.com/backup-restore-sqlite/). It's for Linux but there are same command-line tools for other operating systems as well.